# stackoverflow tag problem Vo or entity or seperate root agg

Tags: domain-driven-design

In the context of domain driven design, tag in stackoverflow is value type, see below link discussion.

[DDD: SO tag. An Entity or value type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679046/ddd-so-tag-an-entity-or-value-type)

But if it is value type then in future if any one wants to create new tag, how will he perform that ?

in my project is also there is **tag** which is associated with an advertisement entity, 1 to many, but if i consider tag as a value type and in future if i want to add new tag in data base . How would i do that, because tag is VO. while creating advertisement i can only assign existing tag to a new advertisement , **but how will i create new tag**?

Answer (score 1):

In the context of the list of possible tags, tag is an entity.

A tag as applied to a question is a value type.  In fact, it's not even a class from the order's perspective - it's really just a string.

Answer (score 1):

Tag is an entity. It has conceptual identity, please see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679046/ddd-so-tag-an-entity-or-value-type/7028680#7028680). You create it just like you create any other entities.