# Building a tag/category system

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I am trying to create a dynamic website that needs a category system - sort of like what there is on this site.

I need entries to the database to be able to have categories that they are under so that if someone selects a category, I can easily find all entries under that category... Nothing more advanced than that.

So far, the way I have thought about it is to add the following to the individual entries:

```
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
```

And then for `Category`, I have:

```
 public class Category
 {

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

I still need to work out a way to have a select box and save the list/create new categories, but, I don't imagine this being that hard. I tried looking at the EF generated data from this, and, it looked a little bit mucky which got me concerned. I am just very hesitant before going any further as this seemed too easy and I am sure I have overlooked something....

...I just don't know if I am on the right track at all and was wondering if someone who has done this before can give any advice?

Comment: Wil, what specifically are you asking here?  Knowing that will help.  Do you have a DB structure defined (with tables for Categories, Entries, and a map from Categories to Entries)?  It sounds like you've generated the Model.edmx.  Did you generate model classes from this?  EF makes it straightforward enough to auto-generate the model classes and from there you can create the various viewmodel classes, pass those to your views and write the controller actions to facilitate that.  It's hard to know if you are on the right track at this point, honestly.

Comment: I agree, this is a bit too fuzzy to provide a solution for.

Comment: @itsmatt It is awkward to explain - basically, I just have a database of items and I want to be able to assign (multiple) categories to each item... Sort of in the same way as you add tags to questions here. I am just having a hard time trying to understand how to set the database up for this. ... I hope that explains a little more.

Comment: @wil - see my answer.  Maybe it is helpful for the DB part.  There's plenty after that but, assuming you did a DB-first approach, you could have EF-generated models for those pretty easily.

Comment: @wil: take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/679046/625332 (it is more about DDD than about database though).

Comment: What are you having difficulty with, is it the database design? The UI?. Maybe you could expand your question. At the moment it's a bit vague. When you've done that please flag to re-open. Thanks.

Comment: @Kev - it is really the database design for a tagging system. Itsmatt has really answered it now, but I wanted to wait in case there were any better answers. I will try to rephrase in the morning. Sorry and thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assume I've got Questions and Tags  they might look like this:

```
Questions
---------
Id
Title
Text

Tags
---------
Id
Name
```

Then a table to map questions to tags

```
QuestionTags
------------
QuestionId
TagId
```

Where `QuestionId` and `TagId` are foreign keys to the `Id` columns of `Questions` and `Tags`, respectively.  And they are, necessarily, the primary key for the `QuestionTags` table (since you don't tag a question with the same tag multiple times).

That might be how I'd lay out the tables, though there are other approaches.